# Error: no matching function for call to 'variable'

Tags: c++, vector

I'm learning c++ and I have initialized a variable (vector of a vector of chars) and then added a function prototype, and then called that function in main.

But I am seeing `error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::vector<char> >::vector(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'`

I think the error message is saying:

"Hey, you tried to call a function `'std::vector<std::vector<char> >::vector(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'` but it doesn't exist."

But as far as I can tell, I never tried to call it as a function, I just tried to initialize it as a variable.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> board {{"5","3",".",".","7",".",".",".","."},{"6",".",".","1","9","5",".",".","."},{".","9","8",".",".",".",".","6","."},{"8",".",".",".","6",".",".",".","3"},{"4",".",".","8",".","3",".",".","1"},{"7",".",".",".","2",".",".",".","6"},{".","6",".",".",".",".","2","8","."},{".",".",".","4","1","9",".",".","5"},{".",".",".",".","8",".",".","7","9"}};
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Expressions like `"5"` are not `char`. They are strings/char arrays (double quoted). In order to initialize a vector of char, use char literals like `'5', '3'` (single quoted)

Comment: It would've been more clear if it said "no matching constructor ...", but the compiler calling it a function isn't much of a stretch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define an object of `std::vector`, the appropriate constructor will be selected to initialize the object. The compiler is just complaining that the appropriate constructor can't be found. Note that the constructor is also a function.

The issue here is that the inner `vector`'s element type is `char`, but `"5"` and `"3"` and so on are c-style strings, i.e. `const char[2]`s, not `char`s.

Change all the `"` to `'`.

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>> board {{'5','3','.','.','7','.','.','.','.'},{'6','.','.','1','9','5','.','.','.'},{'.','9','8','.','.','.','.','6','.'},{'8','.','.','.','6','.','.','.','3'},{'4','.','.','8','.','3','.','.','1'},{'7','.','.','.','2','.','.','.','6'},{'.','6','.','.','.','.','2','8','.'},{'.','.','.','4','1','9','.','.','5'},{'.','.','.','.','8','.','.','7','9'}};
```